# How to replace text in first TD based on the values of table stored in other TD with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple tables stacked inside a div container as below:-

```
<div id="myContent"  style="display: block;">
      <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      Health Care (ID-20)
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      20 Wisconsin Ave</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      641.235.5900
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      No website
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
              <img src="images/phone.png" class="imgHeader" >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
              <table >
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">Housing (ID-25)</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      N/A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      641.255.3884
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      www.housingl.org
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
              <img src="images/phone.png" class="imgHeader" >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      Employment(ID-35)</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">N/A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      641.743.0500
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      http://www.noexperience.org
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
              <img src="images/phone.png" class="imgHeader" >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I am trying to run a condition to find the TD with N/A and remove some contents on the first TD of that table. Precisely, I would like to remove all the text displayed between brackets in the first TD i.e. "(ID-25)" if any of the text in that table is "N/A". How can I accomplish that? Any support is appreciated!!!

Comment: a quick note - ID's are meant to be unique in dom, you have multiple tables with same id 'myTable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('td:contains("N/A")').each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td').first().text($(this).closest('table').find('td').first().text().replace(/\(.*\)/ig, '()'));
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/utxzC/)**

Comment: Thanks, How can I get rid of that brackets too?

Comment: Change this chunk, `.replace(/\(.*\)/ig, '()')` to this `.replace(/\(.*\)/ig, '')`